# Is there any way to list distribution groups and members?

Tags: active-directory

I would like to get a list of distribution groups and their members, and possibly output to an excel spreadsheet. Has anyone tried this before or have any ideas where I should start?

Answer (score 4):

In PowerShell:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq "Distribution"} -Properties Members

ForEach ($g in $Groups) {
    Write-Host $g.name
    Write-Host $g.members `n

}
```

That will write the output to the console. You can play around with `Export-CSV` and the other usual suspects to get it into the final format that you want.